# Is there a way to use Pyhton in websites?

Tags: python, web

I need to make a very specific program to calculate text RPG results based on user inputs, currently Im making it in Python because thats what I know to use, but we play in a website and most players dont have any program to use Python and some even play on their phones, is there any way to play it on a website?

I've looked for ways and most sources said I need to convert it to HTML or another language like C or C++, but I dont even know how to do this and the auto-converters I've tried didnt worked. Jupyter Notebook also wouldnt work because some of the players doesnt know how to use it and it would be too hard to teach them all.

Is there ANY way to keep it in Python and use it on a website?

Comment: Make a backend in Python using something like FastAPI, make a UI frontend with JS.

Comment: There are various web-based python interpreters. See for example [link](https://www.online-python.com/) or [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/)

Comment: Have a look at https://www.fullstackpython.com/web-development.html

Comment: I've heard of people using Python on Glitch.com. Is your code okay being public? You can use appmode or Voila so your non-coding friends don't need to see the Jupyter notebook, and use the Mybinder service to offer temporary sessions. Go to [appmode github page](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode#try-it-live) on your phone using its browser. Scroll down to where it says 'Try it Live' and click 'launch binder'. You should see a calculator app open on your phone. That is backed by a notebook running on a temporary remote session via the MyBinder service. Voila is fancier & newer but similar.

Comment: For a Voila example, I'm going to suggest the iexFinder one. Sadly, the link is currently broken on the Voila Gallery page (I submitted a pull request to fix it.) So click the 'Source' text **below** the tile for now. End up [here](https://github.com/zolabar/IexFinder) on your phone and click on the `launch binder` badge on the bottom (or far right) to open it as an app. Keep in mind they didn't set it up for really bing able to use well on a phone but it should help give you an idea. You can edit the main formula near the top and then hit 'Update'. Scroll to the right to see the fancy plot.

Comment: [Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/). Documentation for Voila is [here](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).  **Different tack to this problem:** The new darling of Python in a web browser is Pyscript, see [Pyscript examples in action](https://pyscript.net/examples/). Because you have to deal with passing the input or triggers to Python and back again to the HTML/javascript, at this time it can still be a challenge putting all the pieces together, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75229302/trying-to-run-python-in-html#comment132753232_75229302).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any python web framework and host it.
If you are a beginner, I recommend you to use Flask framework and try hosting it in https://www.pythonanywhere.com/